# Setting draft value of rich text area with javascript (Trix/ActiveText)

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, rich-text-editor, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a 'save draft' button which successfully saves message content as a draft. When the page loads with a draft, I add the following script to the HTML:

```
<% if @draft_msg.present? %>
  <script>
    const richInput = document.querySelector('trix-editor');
    richInput.innerHTML = `<%= @draft_msg.content %>`;
  </script>
<% end %>
```

This renders as something like this:

```
<script>
    const richInput = document.querySelector('trix-editor');
    richInput.innerHTML = `<div class="trix-content">
  <div>zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</div>
</div>
`;
</script>
```

When I was working on the page and refreshing between edits I thought I had everything working, as my draft value was present inside my rich text editor. However when I go from my index page to a 'Talk' page (which has the rich text editor and a draft), the innerHTML is not changed.

The script is still loaded and looks like this:

```
<script>
    const richInput = document.querySelector('trix-editor');
    richInput.innerHTML = `<div class="trix-content">
  <div>zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</div>
</div>
`;
  </script>
```

If I refresh the page it is working again!

I am not sure why this is.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBk_zalHnac

This tutorial 'Ruby on Rails - Railscasts #324 Passing Data To Javascript' helped me solve this problem. Passing ruby on rails data to a javascript file is easy if you:

1) In your html.erb file write:

```
# views/model_name/show.html.erb
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  window.variableName = `<%= @rails_instance.data %>`;
<% end %>
```

2) In the javascript file you can then use variableName as a variable

```
// javascript/components/file_name.js
console.log(variableName)
```

It might be important to know that I have a separate javascript pack 'on_new_page.js' which loads at the bottom of application.html.erb to skip rails's turbolinks. In this 'on_new_page.js' file the function inside of 'javascript/components/file_name.js' is called.

```
views/layouts/application.html.erb
    ...        
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'on_new_page' %>
  </body>
</html>
```